# Uploading XML file to the Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking for the best way to upload the XML file to the GAE DataStore from the web page. The XML will be later parsed and modified wia the web interface. So far I am using the HTML`form` with file type`input`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update" method="post" > 
  <input type="file" name="myfile" /> 
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

In the servlet class I use the for loop to read the data into `String`:

```
InputStream input = req.getInputStream();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(""); 

int c = -1;
while ( (c = input.read() ) != -1 ) 
{
  char ch = (char) c;
  sb.append( ch );
}
```

Then I check if the DataStore contains the entity with application hardcoded key value and if not I create a new entity and upload the XML into `Text` (`com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text`), otherwise I create a new entity and put the file there. Is that something you can call the good approach?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a html form with `type="file"` field, then browser will upload the file via http POST with a [`multipart/form-data` content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

See AppEngine docs on [how to handle properly multipart content data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms).